# Proof of recursion theorem

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I was going through a real analysis textbook [The Real Numbers and Real Analysis](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=r0qcU9U2_I4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=real%20numbers%20and%20real%20analysis%20ethan%20bloch&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8iqgVYrHCKaE7ga0k6boDA&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=real%20numbers%20and%20real%20analysis%20ethan%20bloch&f=false/) this morning, and I encountered a theorem stating that:

Let $H$ be a set, let $e\in H$ and $k:H\rightarrow H$ be a function. Then there always exists a unique function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow H$ such that $f(1)=e$, and that $f(n+1)=k(f(n))$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

As a 1st year undergrad in maths, I have little knowledge in set theory except for the basics, but I simply couldn't help but wonder why does one have to consider the set $$C=\lbrace W\subseteq \mathbb{N}\times H\mid (1,e) \in W,\,\text{and if}\,(n,y)\in W,\,(n+1,k(y))\in W\rbrace$$ and let $f=\bigcap W\in C$ to prove $f$ does have the desired property and it is indeed a function.

Instead, could I not just define the relation to be $$W=\lbrace (a,b)\in \mathbb{N}\times H\mid (1,e) \in W,\,\text{and if}\,(n,y)\in W,\,(n+1,k(y))\in W\rbrace?$$

I know this sounds rather silly, but is there a reason why I can't define a set in this way? Is it because that the set builder notation actually involves the set itself, so I have to justify the existence of such a set beforehand? Or is it because of some other reason?

Comment: Stupid question: What is $e$, the Euler number, or some generic element? I think the latter.

Comment: yes, it's just a generic element in H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we just say that

$$W=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{N}\times H \mid (1,e) \in W,\ \text{and if}\ (n,y)\in W,\ (n+1,k(y))\in W\}.$$

As an example, assuming $k$ is not the identity function,
$W$ could contain the following distinct elements:

$$(1,e)$$
$$(2,k(e))$$
$$(2,e)$$

Then $W$ must also contain the elements

$$(3,k(k(e)))$$
$$(3,k(e))$$

and indeed many more elements. But there is nothing that prevents $W$
from containing all the elements already mentioned.

This creates problems. First, there are a lot of different ways to
construct a set $W$ that meets this requirement
($W$ might contain $(2,e)$, or it might not), 
so really $W$ is not a well defined set at all.
Second, a lot of the sets we could construct along the lines of
this "definition" (for example any such set containing the elements
listed above) are not functions. (They have more than one right-hand
element associated with the same left-hand element.)

But when you consider *all* possible sets $W$ satisfying the given conditions,
you see that $(2,e)$ is not an element of *every* such set.
Therefore the intersection of all such sets
will not contain $(2,e)$ or any of the other elements that prevent
many of the sets $W$ from being functions.
The intersection contains only the desired elements
$(1,e)$, $(2,k(e))$, $(3,k(k(e)))$, and so forth.

Comment: I see. But if we put this specific theorem aside, and just consider whether I could define a set using notations that involves the set itself, would that be feasible then?

Comment: $W$ as defined above would still be ambiguously defined, even if it were OK that it's not necessarily a function. I'm reluctant to say you can _never_ define a set using a predicate that mentions itself, because someone may come up with a clever counterexample; but it's hard to imagine why one would _want_ to try to write such a definition.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it really helps me a lot, especially in the summer holiday when I won't be able to see any of my lecturers.

Comment: @wanwuwi: You can use recursive definitions to define things only if you allow it to be partial in a certain sense. To see why one just has to consider the Russell construction "Let $S=\{ x : x \notin x \}$.". It cannot refer to a set without being self-contradictory. However, if we think of the notation $x \in y$ as simply $1_y(x)$ (the indicator function for $y$ applied to $x$), then it clearly may not halt if $1_y$ is a partial function. So $S = \{ x : x \notin x \}$ would define a partial function that does not halt on itself as input. Indeed both $S \in S$ and $S \notin S$ would not halt.

Comment: @wanwuwi: Similarly, both "Let $S = \{ x : x = S \}$" and "Let $S = \{ x : x \ne S \}$" would define partial functions that never halt on any input. And I should say that in conventional set theory all sets are essentially total functions on the universe, so you cannot do any of these recursive constructions there.

Comment: @wanwuwi: So if it is not clear, in conventional set theory, you **cannot** define a set using a predicate that mentions itself.

Answer (score 3):

You want to prove the existence of a function. This means that you have to come up with the set of ordered pairs which is that function.

In the proof given in the book, we define a collection of relations, whose intersection is the wanted function.

What you suggest suffers from one of two possible problems:

1. Either this is not a well-formed definition, since it uses $W$ inside the definition of $W$; or
2. you actually claim that $W$ is a set which is equal to the set defined on the right hand side, but this gives you only the information that $W$ is closed under a certain operation. It, in fact, assumes that $W$ already exists, when you try to prove its existence to begin with.

Instead, the book opts for a different method. First define a collection of relations, then show that they define the wanted function.

Comment: Does it mean that if there is a way to rephrase the statement such that it does not involves $W$(which I know probably doesn't exist), then defining the set in this way would be possible?

Comment: @wanwuwi: The point is that you cannot define something in terms of itself. That is called **circular** and will get you nowhere. It's just like defining "the" as "the word that is used as the definite article in English". If you didn't already know what "the" means, can you understand what it means after reading my definition?

Answer (score -1):

> Instead, could I not just define the relation to be $$W=\lbrace
>  (a,b)\in \mathbb{N}\times H\mid (1,e) \in W,\,\text{and if}\,(n,y)\in
>  W,\,(n+1,k(y))\in W\rbrace?$$
>
> I know this sounds rather silly, but is there a reason why I can't
>   define a set in this way? Is it because that the set builder notation
>   actually involves the set itself, so I have to justify the existence
>   of such a set beforehand?

My opinion is that this is not a definition by itself. What we have here is the bootstrap process used by the Peano axioms for characterisation of the natural numbers. (See below)

You can write it more suggestive as
$$
\begin{matrix}
(1,e) \in W \\
(n,y) \in W \Rightarrow (n+1,k(y)) \in W
\end{matrix}
\quad (*)
$$
this seems a legitimate recursive definition of a set $W$ to me. Note that the inductive clause requires $(n,y) \in W$ and does not permit any choice from $\mathbb{N} \times H$.

Further it seems evident to me that
$$
W = \{ (n, k^{n-1}(e)) \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \} \quad (**)
$$
where $k^m$ means the $m$-fold application of the function $k$,e.g. $k^3 = k \circ k \circ k$, with the special case $k^0 = \mbox{id}$ and that this can be seen as graph of a function $f$:
$$
G_f = \{ (n, f(n)) \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}  = W
$$
or in other words
$$
f(n) = k^{n-1} (e) \quad (n \in \mathbb{N})
$$

We have $W \subseteq \mathbb{N}\times H$ because for the first component $1 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow n+1 \in \mathbb{N}$ (see Peano axioms). For the second component we have $e \in H$ and due to $k : H \to H$ we have $k^{n-1}(e) \in H$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

It is my believe that $(*)$ leads to just $(**)$, there are no more elements in $W$. And here I am unsure, if I can get away with just that or not.

The problem I have with your excerpt of that proof is

- I lack the imagination for more than one possible set $W$ within $C$. If I am correct that would make the intersection trivial and unnecessary
- if there are different $W$ I would really need to be able to imagine them at least to that detail that I am able to perform the intersection

Comment: Why would you get that $W$ is a function? All this definition gives you is that $W$ supersets the wanted function. But $\Bbb N\times H$ satisfies the definition you present as well.

Comment: $(1,e)\in\Bbb N\times H$? Yes. If $(n,y)\in\Bbb N\times H$, is $(n+1,k(y))\in\Bbb N\times H$? Yes. Therefore $W=\Bbb N\times H$. Doesn't seem to work very well if $H$ has more than one element.

Comment: Yes, $W$ is a set. Functions are sets. I don't understand your comment... (Sorry for posting several comments at once!)

Comment: Again, check the definition against $\Bbb N\times H$ and see that it fits. Is it a function?

Comment: I believe $W \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times H$ and in general not equal to $\mathbb{N}\times H$, because $y$ is not allowed to be an arbitrary element of $H$, like you assume in your argumentation.

Comment: To make *Asaf*'s comment clear, your so-called recursive definition does not specify what is **not** in $W$. In order to do so, you will end up having to do either of two things: (1) construct all sets that satisfy those conditions and then prove that there is at least one such set and then take their intersection (which is what the author of the textbook presumably did; I hope they didn't forget to prove that at least one such set exists otherwise the intersection won't). (2) ... [continued]

Comment: Define a function that extends any function $g$ with domain $[1..m]$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $g(1) = e$ and $g(n+1) = k(g(n))$ for any $n \in [1..m]$ to a function with domain $[1..m+1]$ such that $g(1) = e$ and $g(n+1) = k(g(n))$ for any $n \in [1..m+1]$. Then construct $S = \{ m : m \in \mathbb{N} \land \text{there is a function $g$ on $[1..m]$ such that $g(1) = e$ and $g(n+1) = k(g(n))$ for any $n \in [1..m]$} \}$ and prove by induction that $S = \mathbb{N}$. Then prove that the union of the functions that witness each element in $S$ is a function with the desired properties.

Comment: My recollection is that inductive definitions used in CS (like (*) in this answer) are shorthand for a more rigorous definition in which the defined set is not just _any_ set that satisfies both clauses, but is the closure (under the second clause) of a set enumerated in the first clause (in this case, the set $\{(1,e)\}$. So we have to define what is meant by "closure" here. I think usually this is done by building up a union of sets (like (2) in @user21820's comment), but a method like $\bigcap_{W\in C} W$ (as in the original question) seems to me to be a reasonable alternative.

Comment: Indeed many people use all sorts of shorthand notation to do recursive definitions. That is fine as long as those notations are precisely spelt out before using them. The reason I don't agree with you answer is because the asker is explicitly asking about those (fine-print) details, so it is not alright to just say that the shorthand definition is perfectly legitimate. Also, I realized I didn't answer your question about whether ( * ) is the same as ( ** ). Yes it is, but ( ** ) is circular since it assumes we can do iterated function composition, which is precisely what this theorem is about!

Comment: @user21820 Asaf's comment is outdated, referring to an older version of this answer.

Comment: @user21820 The inductive / recursive generation of $W$ starts with a single element from the first clause. And is then extended by the second clause, and nothing else.

Comment: I am not happy, because I see that Peano did put so much technical effort in the rather obvious seeming construction of $\mathbb{N}$ used in the first component of $W$, while I use the similar construction for the second component without similar technical depth. I have to consult a good book on recursion theory.  user21820 is right that this is about the fine print, so I agree with the downvote. I hope to revisit soon.